Question about Rudin's proof for: if $E$ is an infinite subset of a compact set $K$, then $E$ has a limit point in $K$.

If $E$ is an infinite subset of a compact set $K$, then $E$ has a limit point in $K$.

Here's Rudin's proof of the theorem.

If no point of $K$ were a limit point of $E$, then each $q$ in $K$ would have a neighborhood $V_q$ which contains at most one point of $E$ (namely $q$, if $q$ is in $E$). It is clear that no finite subcollection of $\{V_q\}$ can cover $E$; and the same is true of $K$, since $E$ is a subset of $K$. This contradicts the compactness of $K$.

What bothers me here is this sentence: "and the same is true of $K$, since $E$ is a subset of $K$". How are we allowed to make a conclusion about $K$ based on just the information about its subset in this case? Rudin's argument has only shown that $E$ is not compact, but that by itself is not sufficient to conclude that $K$ is not compact simply because $E$ is a subset of $K$. For example, $[0, 10]$ is compact and $(1, 2)$ is a subset of $[0, 10]$ which is not compact, so it seems like by employing Rudin's argument here I would now conclude that I have a contradiction (which is of course absurd). What am I missing here?

You got an open cover of the whole space $K$. $K$ is compact so you have a finite subcover that covers $K$. As $E$ is a subset of $K$, that subcover also covers $E$, a contradiction.

The argument is not: if $(1,2)$ is not compact, then $[0,10]$ cannot be compact either. It is that you have found a cover of $[0,10]$ that does not have a finite subcover of $(1,2)$. This contradicts compactness of $[0,10]$, since that open cover must have a finite subcover of $[0,10]$, which is a finite subcover of $(1,2)$ too. In your case, $\{V_q\}$ is an open cover of $K$. If it had a finite subcover $\{V_{q_i}\}$, then it would be a cover of $E$ too. But then $E$ would have to be finite, a contradiction.
Hope this helps. :>
